# Vim Delete From the Character Directly After the First Character of a Word Until the End of the Word

Tags: vim, neovim

Say I have

```
word
^ Cursor Here
```

and I want it to be

```
w
```

If I use `de` I end up just deleting the entire word. I could just press the right arrow key once but that requires me to lift my hands defeats the purpose. I Need a way to delete from the character directly following until the end of the word. I could be overdoing it a little here though.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a remap, then you can create a shortcut for it. For instance:

`noremap <C-t> :norm lde<Cr>`

will remap `ctrl+t` to move right with `l`, delete to end `de`, then enter `<CR>`. This assumes your cursor is at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the map is unnecessary. If the point is to avoid moving the hand, `l` is a solution on its own purely because it's on the home row

Comment: True. If the question had been "how to move right without using arrows" I would have just suggested `hjkl`, but the question seemed like it specifically wanted a hotkey for this one action. But fair point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using the arrow keys to move rather than `hjkl`
keys.

While it feels very wrong to use them when you've been used to the arrow
keys from so many other programs, it only takes a week or two of forcing
yourself to use `hjkl`. Once that's done, the benefits are with you for every
extra second, minute, hour you spend in vim for as long as you use it as your editor.

In your case you would just type `lde` to move right one character, and delete to the
beginning of the next word.